# Angular Auth Service - too many calls

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, nx-workspace

i'm currently working on a Angular Web App. For authentication i (want to) use JWT, but due to the Backend not being ready **atm**, i'm just using a mock function.
I have both a `Auth.service.ts` for the Authentication Procedure and a `Guard.service.ts` that makes sure that someone who is not logged-in cannot activate certain Routes. 
I'm storing a Session Token in `localStorage` and have a `isAuthenticated = new Subject<boolean>()` in `Auth.service.ts` that store the Token an a boolean Value that indicates wheather the User had been logged in or not. 
My `Auth.service.ts` has the following Code:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.isAuthenticated.next(false)
  }

  public isAuthenticated = new Subject<boolean>()
  public CheckAuthentication = () => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('authToken') === 'AUTH_TOKEN') {
      this.isAuthenticated.next(true)
      return true
    } else {
      this.isAuthenticated.next(false)
      return false
    }
  }

  public Login = async (username: string, password: string) => {
    if (username == 'admin' && password == 'admin') {
      localStorage.setItem('authToken', 'AUTH_TOKEN')
      await this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']).then(() => window.location.reload())
    }
  }

  public Logout = async () => {
    localStorage.clear()
    await this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']).then(() => window.location.reload())
  }
}
```

This is the `Guard.service.ts`

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GuardService implements CanActivate, OnDestroy {
  constructor(private router: Router, private auth: AuthService){
  }
   
  ngOnDestroy(): void {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    if(this.auth.CheckAuthentication()) {
      return true 
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/secure/account/login'])
      return false
    }
  }
}
```

Only the `AuthService` is declared as Provider in `app.module.ts` `providers: [AuthService]`

There are a few Components that access/use the `Auth.service.ts` Service

- `Login.component.ts` calls `this.authService.Login(this.loginForm.value.username ?? '', this.loginForm.value.password ?? '')` on the click of a Button
- `Navbar.component.ts` uses a Subscription to `isAuthenticated` to dynamically add a `Login`/`Logout` Button

Just to be sure, i'm going to add the Entire Navbar Code:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'navbar',
  template: `
<p-menubar [model]="this.menuItems">
  <ng-template pTemplate="start">
      <img src="../../assets/img/muetec.png" height="40" class="mr-2" />
  </ng-template>
</p-menubar>
`
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnDestroy{
  menuItems: MenuItem[]
  private isAuthSub: Subscription

  constructor(public auth: AuthService) {
    this.isAuthSub = this.auth.isAuthenticated.subscribe(s => this.updateBar(s))
    this.menuItems = []
  }

  updateBar(s: boolean) {
    // If user is authenticated
    if (s) {
      // Add Logout Button
      this.menuItems.find(mi => mi.label == 'Account')?.items?.push(
        { label: 'Logout', icon: 'pi pi-lock-closed', routerLink: [ '/secure/account/logout' ] }
      )
      // Remove Login Button
    // If user ist not authenticated
    } else if(!s) {
      // Add Login Button
      this.menuItems.find(mi => mi.label == 'Account')?.items?.push(
        { label: 'Login', icon: 'pi pi-lock-open', routerLink: [ '/secure/account/login' ] }
      )    
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
      this.isAuthSub.unsubscribe()
  }
}
```

I get the Following Error:

> Too many calls to Location or History APIs within a short timeframe.

from two Files: `auth.service.ts` and `common.mjs` *after* Clicking the Login Button and in the Login Form, i get redirect back to the Dashboard and after that, the Angular Router does not show anything and a few seconds later i get that message

Note: I'm using Angular with NX Workspaces

Below is a Screenshot of that Error.
Can anyone help me?

[image: Screenshot of Error Message in Browser]

Comment: It seems you have a redirect loop your guard might be redirecting to a route that requires authentication. That might cause a redirect loop.

Comment: Just a hint: You can use [Angular http interceptors](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) for adding jwt token. For example you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/@auth0/angular-jwt. Of course you have to check if it cares about login/logout.